# [tag[[Errno 13][/tag] Permission denied

Tags: scala, sbt, sublimetext2

I am trying to build .scala file using sublime text 2 and ensime. I have ensime configured for sublime text 2, also sbt is in class path(not sure if it is, since when i try to run sbt from terminal it executes).

So when i try to build, i get below in the sublime console.

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied
[cmd:  [u'/usr/local/bin/sbt', u'-Dsbt.log.noformat=true', u'compile']]
[dir:  /Users/chetankokil/Documents/scalateral]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

Regards
Chetan

Comment: To be clear, your question is just about what this error means and how to fix it?

Comment: Yup thats right, i am trying to understand why this error and how to get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permission of sbt file.

If used brew to install sbt:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.13.9/bin/sbt
```